# Ask for permissions without adding in manifest

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

Can I ask on Android 7+ for permissions without declaring them in the manifest, because I'm writing code on my mobile and I can't edit tge manifest (Sketchware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  They need to be in the manifest, and possibly requested at runtime (depending on the permission).

Answer (score 1):

Manifest is one of the major part of Android App, it specifics what all can be accessed by the app. We cannot get permission unless it's specified in it. So try to add in it ,Cheers :)